# Multivariate Testing in Ektron

Tags: ektron

I am working in Ektron 8.6.

I am working with Multivariate Experiment.

After setting an experiment, I could see proper results in experiment widget (both HITs and Conversions). But the issue is with multivariate_report table, it’s not updating HIT or Conversion over there.  Problem if it’s not updated on the DB is that you will lose the results if you restart IIS (SESSION is lost).  While digging deep into the same I could find that the GUID in table data is not matching with variant GUID. Seems that it’s a BUG with Ektron.  I am using Version: 8.60 SP1(Build 8.6.0.060) of Ektron.

Did anyone else had similar issues with multivariate test?

Comment: I think the results may get periodically flushed to DB. Do the results end up in multivariate_report eventually?

Comment: After restart of IIS multivariate_report is not showing results

Comment: If you let the site sit for some time (say 15 minutes), do results get entered into the DB?

Comment: No,Database table multivariate_report is not showing up Hit/Conversion.It is showing 0 Hit and 0 Conversion.(Even after 15 mins)